# colored level indicator example

Tags: android

Anybody can share code snippet for cocoa-like nslevelindicator:

[image]

I was looking to LevelListDrawable and StateListDrawable but it not looks like what i need.

Comment: Looks to me like a `ProgressBar` with either a `LevelListDrawable` or just replacing the background at whatever the color-change break points are.

Comment: @CommonsWare peace of code will appreciated